# why project structure when clone flutter like this?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i cant run a project or get the right project structure when clone project from github.

have any one an idea help me  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

clone project with android studio
`File -> New -> Project from Version Control`  
and wait until your project synced